# Ember.js: Howto create routes that only execute code

Tags: javascript, ember.js, transition

My app has a main view with some hidden elements that can be activated by the user. Like a typical sidebar on mobiles that slides in from the left. Or a cart that reveals the details when you tap on it.

The information in those initially hidden elements is always up to date since their content is mapped in the main app template. So my routes would not need to render any DOM.

The transitions are JS based. But now I want those states to be reflected in the URL, in order to get a consistent back button behavior.

How can I achieve that using the ember framework?

**Update** to make it more clear, what I am talking about:

To my understanding triggering routes in ember has mainly two side-effects:

1. Represent the new state in the URL, enabling consistent browser history support.
2. Render templates that manipulate the DOM based on some data

In my case, when for instance a user taps on the minimized cart I need:

1. Represent the new state in the URL, enabling consistent browser history support.
2. Execute my `showCart()` JS Function (no DOM changes, no template rendering)

When the user now taps on the browser back button, `closeCart()` should be executed (based on the fact that the state in the URL carries the information that the cart is open).

Comment: I don't get your question. Do you want an overview about what is the ember approach to solve that kind of problems? I am confuse with the title `How to create routes that only execute code`.

Comment: @Márcio Rodrigues Correa Júnior: I just updated the question to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `activate` and `deactivate` methods from your show route, to know when is entered or exited from your route:

```
App.ShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        alert('Entering in show');
        // here would be your showCart
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        alert('Exiting from show');
        // and here the closeCart
    }
});
```

I created a live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/4fxbT/) here, to you see this working.

Comment: This wouldn't work from anywhere in the application, it would only work from a single route.  If you attempted to access this route from a deeply nested route it would destroy the entire view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, where can they access these slide in windows?  Can they only be accessed from a single location in your route map?  Or can the user click on it regardless of whatever view they are in?  And if they click it from different views, do you move them back to a different route just to pop out some slide in window?

If they can only click it from one place, then you could just add code in your setupController of that specific route to fire the js to slide out the window.

```
 setupController: function(){
   Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
    //run some js to slide out the window
    });
 }
```

Honestly if they can click a button anywhere and have the slide out appear, I wouldn't try putting it into the url.  Just my opinion though.

Comment: Please see my updated quetsion for some more info. And the reason why I need the URL changes is that the users intuitively press the browser back button to get back to the previous state ('cart details closed' for instance).

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still outside of the ember paradigm.  Your description of your shopping cart and the url updating with it, wouldn't work with their resource/route setup.

Comment: Maybe this is not the main scenario the creators of ember had in mind. But it is a *real world* one. Therefore I hope to get some ideas for workarounds. Telling me that my requirements are "out of paradigm" is not really helpful.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean to you, nor say your scenario isn't a real world scenario, I'm saying it won't work with the internal routing of ember.  The workaround would be to rewrite the entire Ember Router class and force it to ignore the tree structure of its routes, and just look for a route anywhere in the tree.

Comment: I see your point, that the routing behavior has to be adapted. So right now I am checking if [ember-animated-outlet](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet) could be a starting point.