# How to save app state in the url

Tags: ember.js

I've created in my Ember App a sliding panel with some news;
i would like the panel's state (open or close) to be saved in the URL;

for example, i would like that when I am on the page:

```
domain.com/home
```

and I opend the panel, the URL becomes

```
domain.com/home/panel
```

(or something similar) and the panel template is rendered in the panel outlet (keeping the home template in the main outlet)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is here in my answer: [Ember.js: Howto create routes that only execute code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111466/ember-js-howto-create-routes-that-only-execute-code/18118593#18118593)

The real issue is where would the `route` live?  If it lives at the root, when you toggle the visible state of it you would have to transition the route.  Which would then leave any deeper routes and just go to that route.

```
 App.Router.map(function() {
   this.route('slideOut', {path:':is_visible'});

   this.resource('foo', function() {
     this.resource('foo.bar', { path: '/bar' }, function() {
       this.route('baz'); // This will be foo.bar.baz
     });
   });
 });
```

Now you might be wondering, why can't I just update the property is_visible on the slideOut model (if it were the top level resource).  The problem is, updating ids on a model won't update the url.  It's only updated during a transition.